# Json data containing NaN results in error during ajax request

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I an endpoint exposed via web api which spews out JSON like this:

```
"[{"SomeId":1,"SomeName":"Some name 1","Parameter1":1.13,"Parameter2":3.0 ...
```

to jquery ajax get requests. Everything works fine until the JSON contains NaN (not a number):

```
"[{"SomeId":1,"SomeName":"Some name 1","Parameter1":1.13,"Parameter2":NaN ...
```

If this type of data is returned the error callback is hit.

Is this a known issue? Is jquery or web api to blame? How can I mitigate this? Thanks.

Comment: Check the response in the network tab of your browser's dev tools to see if the NaN is being sent from the server. Are you doing anything funky to build the response, or just letting Web API do it?

Comment: Web api builds it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because the token `NaN` is invalid in [JSON](http://json.org). JSON is a *subset* of JavaScript's object initializer syntax, which doesn't include several aspects of it, including `NaN` (and `Infinity`, `undefined`, ...).

The web API providing that output is producing invalid JSON, so any conforming JSON parser will complain about it. You'll need to fix (or ask the providers of it to fix) the API.

Comment: Thanks. Google told me about something like this. It still does not make sense to me. At the end of the day JSON contains key value pairs. Why is NaN not being treated as string? Or does JavaScript's object initializer look for these 'keywords' and spits its dummy?

Comment: @csetzkorn: *"Why is NaN not being treated as string?"* Why *would* it be? It's not in quotes. *"Or does JavaScript's object initializer look for these 'keywords' and spits its dummy?"* `NaN` is a JavaScript keyword, yes; it *isn't* a JSON keyword. JSON is not JavaScript, JSON is JSON, a textual notation for data interchange *based on* JavaScript object initializer syntax, but not the same as it.

Comment: Thanks. Pardon the pun about the 'dummy' (-: